# Should there be a vtc option for "I'm convinced this user is a sockpuppet"?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, duplicate-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it allowed to have multiple AU accounts, intentionally, without having them merged?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3302/is-it-allowed-to-have-multiple-au-accounts-intentionally-without-having-them-m)

For example I provide chat logs:
http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5394002#5394002

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have able and present moderators that have the tools to decide if a user is voting on his other accounts with the intent of inflating his reputation.

Voting, accusing a user of sock-puppeting,  is not and will not - imo - be of any use for normal users and I refuse to imagine how can that be of any good for the site.

There is no rule that says a user can have only one registered account on the site, and if not created for wrong purposes, he can have as many as he wishes.